# best/shortest way to draw 1px grid in SVG

Tags: html, grid, svg, draw

I need to draw a 1px grid (10px spacing) using the SVG canvas embedded within a webpage. There are many SVG tags to choose from and I was hoping someone could suggest what tags would be best suited for the job and produce the least amount of code.

For instance, is there a shorter alternative to plotting the path using the <path> tag? Perhaps by defining a square 10px x 10px then somehow repeating it accross the canvas.

Anyway, open to suggestions please.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can make a `<pattern>` (essentially the tile in your question) and fill any shape with that.

Here's an [example](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/harness/htmlObjectApproved/pservers-pattern-01-b.html) of that technique.

Comment: Nice. This looks like the solution for me. Will run some tests.

Comment: Any new faster methods? now that this is quite a few years old!

Comment: It's possible to use a css background (which can be an svg file), assuming that you want to fill the svg canvas, and not some arbitrary shape. AFAIK no browser implements the <hatch> element from svg2 yet, but that should also be able to do this. See https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/pservers.html#Hatches.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert (day 3!), but I do know that Google uses rects to do this on Google charts, with either a width or a height equal to 1. Nothing fancy, just write the grid with lots of stuff like this:

```
<rect x="86" y="61" width="1" height="198" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-dasharray="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect>
```

Why do they do this? Don't know. Their graphics are good, so someone has presumably thought about it. My own inclination is to do this with paths, using 'h' and 'v' for relative horizontal and vertical lines. It's more compact, but the output may not be so good.

Comment: Stroking shapes can be expensive, so I'm guessing that might be why rects without stroke are used (instead of e.g lines). Rects also tend to get optimized by the viewers.